# Использование AdMob в активности

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, google-adsense

У меня в приложение XML с ListView и AdView. Но у меня две активности которые используют этот XML(т.к. список через адаптер). Я знаю что на разные активности вроде нужен разный идентификатор баннера, мне нужно и под другую активность делать другой XML и другой баннер вставлять?

Comment: При чем тут тег Adsense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и так и сяк.

1. Создавать/настраивать баннер программно. Тогда не надо разметку менять. Вот [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15954373/3212712) программного создания и отображения баннера:

```
LinearLayout adContainer = <container>;
AdView adView = new AdView(activity)
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(<your-publisher-id>);

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

// Place the ad view.
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
adContainer.addView(adView, params);
```

2. Также можно использовать разную разметку для разных активити и в ней (разметке) задать нужные параметры.